# AWS CLI - aws configure command valid credentials returns error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I recently installed the aws cli on my machine and when I run the command

`$ aws version`

it returns

`$ aws-cli/1.11.137 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.6.4`

so I know it is appropriately installed. However when I run the command

`$ aws configure`

then copy and paste the **AWS Access Key ID** and the **AWS Secret Access Key** from the credentials csv generated by the aws.console (when you create a new user) into the terminal.

Next I type the command

`$ aws iam list-users`

it returns

`Unknown output type: ENTER`

Instead of the output

```
"Users": [
    {
        "UserName": "Adele",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2013-03-07T05:14:48Z",
        "UserId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Adele"
    }]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized now that when it prompts you for a default output format you need to enter `json` to get the output I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how I got into a bad state but my ~/.aws/config had some parameters improperly specified. Editing the file manually fixed my issue.

The info under **Configuration Settings and Precedence**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html led me to the right place.